# XML Parsing with Symfony

Tags: php, xml, symfony

I have a XML file in a url. I want to parse data from the xml and to hydrate my entity.

I've code that (crawler) but this does not work (empty response).

```
public function getUsersAction(Request $request)
{
    $crawler = new Crawler();
    $crawler->addXmlContent(
        file_get_contents(
            'http://localhost/myproject/web/feed-users.xml'
        )
    );

    json_encode($crawler);

    return new JsonResponse(
        array(
            'crawler' => $crawler
        )
    );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your $crawler after you injected xml feed in it.

```
use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\CssSelector;

public function getUsersAction(Request $request)
{

    CssSelector::disableHtmlExtension();
    $crawler = new Crawler(file_get_contents('http://localhost/myproject/web/feed-users.xml'));

    $value = $crawler->filter('.someCssSelectorForInstance');
}
```

You can `dump($crawler)` after injecting the xml feed and you'll see that your crawler is ready to go

Answer (score 0):

Try that.

```
 public function ConvertXmlToJson(){
    $url = 'https://host/yourxml.xml';
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($url);
    $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
    $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
    $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);

    return new JsonResponse($simpleXml);
}
```